# TSQL query to result in a very time-consuming, it automatically work every morning, I want the results to be stored

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have TSQL query to result in a very time-consuming .i execute it every morning. I want the results to be stored. But it is very time-consuming . i just need queries result . it may be 100 rows . i guess ssrs anough for me . i am new about ssrs . i have ms vs2013 and  sqlserver 2012 , ms winnserver 2012 environment .

What is the best way or effective way to do it ?

ty guys. but it doesnt fix my job .i dont  send mail . i just store  result set of  query that is  very time consuming . i ll  use  the result set  at my asp.net pages  as  a report . many different report styles but result set always same .when  button1_click event  fire the  stored procedure it ll take  about 50 minutes . i just need  the  generated table with automatic query or anothing thing i dont know . when press button1_click display in aspxgridview1  reslut set  . the result set has got 100 rows at most .but bosses and managers  ll click this button 50 times per day averagely . how can i resolve this with effective method. i have all softwares no express edition. 
i have sql agent. or sheduler. 
i have reporting server but never used it still .
i have asp.net web and database in sqlserver standart edition .

AND thank you very much to responsive friends who isnt waiting for the money

Comment: Sounds more suited to a SQL Agent job rather than SSRS

Comment: @stuartd Depends how the OP wants to use the output. SSRS would work quite well as the results could be cached for 24 hours.

Comment: You could add a new table and use SQL Server agent to truncate this table then insert the results of your query into this new table once a day.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get this is with a job (only unavailable in express, if that is you version more about that later)

Use this proc: sp_send_dbmail
It allows (among many other things) to mail the results of a query as mail body or .csv attachement.

First step is to work out your sendmail query and test it a bit. Once you have that all set you can worry about scheduling it. If you have standard or above you can use the ssms gui to click your way through a new job. This should be pretty selfaxplanetory. In case you use express there is a hillbilly hack you can use to get this working still.

This consists of making a batchfile that execute a sqlcmd command (your sendmail). This can be scheduled from windows scheduled tasks. Please be advised this is not very secure!

Answer (score 1):

I ll try  extra table and  job and automatic .
ty very much steve ford  and  you   all guys helped anybody in software world . I respect you for your  help very much . you are great guys. you all and this site  is  very great for science .

Answer (score 1):

First, run this once to create a table to store your results in.

```
 SELECT col1,Col2,Col3.... 
 INTO NewTable
 FROM YourQuery
```

Second, run this script:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE NewTable

INSERT  INTO NewTable (Col1,Col2,Col3...)
SELECT col1,Col2,Col3.... 
FROM YourQuery
```

If you need this to happen every morning, put this script into a scheduled SQL Agent job. Post back any specific issues you have with this.

Why do you have reporting services in your tags? Are you running a report from this? You'll need to redirect it to your new table.

There are other ways to speed up your report like adding appropriate indexes, refactoring the query